# How can I check if a TERM is assigned with a POST using two parameters term slug and post ID?

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to check whether a post has been assigned with a term but I do not have information about the taxonomy of that term as it could be any taxonomy present in my site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a custom function to return terms for all taxonomies:

```
/**
 * Get terms for all taxonomies
 *
 * @see get_object_taxonomies()
 */
function yourprefix_all_axonomies_terms($post_id) {
    $post       = get_post( $post_id );
    $post_type  = $post->post_type;
    $taxonomies = get_object_taxonomies( $post_type );
    $out        = [ ];

    foreach ( $taxonomies as $taxonomy_slug ){

        // Get the terms related to post.
        $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, $taxonomy_slug );

        if ( ! empty( $terms ) ) {
            foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                $out[] = $term->slug;
            }
        }
    }
    return $out
}
```

Then use it like:

```
if (in_array($term_looked_for, yourprefix_all_axonomies_terms( $post->ID ) ) {
// do your thing
}
```

Comment: One another thing if I can manage to gather POST ID and TERM ID, can it be checked directly without using any function above or how can we do so if we know TERM ID and POST ID and just need to find if POST is assigned to that term..

Comment: You could modify the above function and use `wp_get_object_terms`. (See the docs https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_object_terms). Shouldn't be too hard.